# The game of Craps

Tags: c, boolean, void

Im trying to ask the user to input y or n and the game will either quit or continue. I also want to display the total win and loose and the user quits. Maybe i'm not getting the real hand of boolean and returning stuff in functions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int rollDice(void);
bool playGame(void);

int main(void)
{
    srand((unsigned)(time(NULL)));
    char userInput;
    while (true)
    {
        playGame();
        printf("Would you like to play again?");
        scanf("%c", &userInput);
        if (userInput == 'n' || userInput == 'N')
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
int rollDice(void)
{

    int dice1 = rand()%6+1;
    int dice2 = rand()%6+1;
    int totaldice = dice1 + dice2;

    return totaldice;
}
bool playGame(void)
{
    int point, total;
    int winCounter, looseCounter;
    printf("The game is starting!\n");
    total = rollDice();
    printf("You rolled: %d\n", total);
    if (total == 7 || total == 11)
    {

        printf("Wow it's your lucky day! You Win!\n");
        winCounter++;

    }
    else if (total == 2 || total == 3 || total == 12)
    {
        printf("Unlucky! You Loose!\n");
        looseCounter++;
    }
    else {
        point = total;
        printf("Your Point is: %d\n", point);
        while (true)
        {
            total = rollDice();
            printf("You rolled: %d\n", total);
            if (total == point)
            {
                printf("You made your point! You Win!\n");
                winCounter++;
                break;
            }
            else if (total == 7)
            {
                printf("Thats a %d. You Loose!\n", total);
                looseCounter++;
                break;
            }
        }

    }return true;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%c", &userInput);` --> `scanf(" %c", &userInput);`

Comment: `int winCounter,looseCounter;` --> `int winCounter = 0, looseCounter=0;`

Comment: `return true;` --> `//return true;`

Comment: Hi @ LPs , should i have declared the win/loose counter in the main instead of doing in the play func?

Comment: If you want to count all win an loose of all games, you can simply use static variables inside `paygame` function. I'l update my answer.

Comment: "loose" --> "lose".

Comment: variables on the stack must be initialized before they can successfully be incremented as counters.  As it is, your compiler should have told you about using uninitialized variables for: `winCounter` and `looseCounter`.

Comment: the function `playgame()` returns a `bool`, but that returned value is not being used.  Suggest changing the prototype type to `void playgame( void );`  and the signature to `void playgame()`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding, follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  I.E.  change this line: `}return true;`  (after updating the prototype and signature for `playgame()` to simply `}`  separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank lilne.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that in case of user input something different then `'n'` or `'N'` you terminate the main with `return` instruction.Remove it and the loop can continue.

Better if you use a boolean variable to exit the while loop:

```
int main(void)
{
    srand((unsigned)(time(NULL)));
    char userInput;

    bool paygame = true;

    while (paygame)
    {
        playGame();
        printf("Would you like to play again?");
        scanf(" %c", &userInput);

        printf ("Test: %c\n", userInput);
        if (userInput == 'n' || userInput == 'N')
        {
            paygame = false;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The second big problem are counters of playgame function: they must be inited to 0.

```
int winCounter = 0, looseCounter = 0;
```

Otherwise the count start from a random number.

If you want to count all win and loose of all played games you can simply use static vars:

```
bool playGame(void)
{
    int point, total;
    static int winCounter = 0, looseCounter = 0;
    printf("The game is starting!\n");
    total = rollDice();
    printf("You rolled: %d\n", total);
    if (total == 7 || total == 11)
    {

        printf("Wow it's your lucky day! You Win!\n");
        winCounter++;

    }
    else if (total == 2 || total == 3 || total == 12)
    {
        printf("Unlucky! You Loose!\n");
        looseCounter++;
    }
    else {
        point = total;
        printf("Your Point is: %d\n", point);
        while (true)
        {
            total = rollDice();
            printf("You rolled: %d\n", total);
            if (total == point)
            {
                printf("You made your point! You Win!\n");
                winCounter++;
                break;
            }
            else if (total == 7)
            {
                printf("Thats a %d. You Loose!\n", total);
                looseCounter++;
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    printf ("Won: %d - Lose: %d\n", winCounter, looseCounter);

    return true;
}
```

Last thing change the `scanf` format specifier to `" %c"` to allow `scanf` to "flush" newline `'\n'` char left into `stdin` after each input by user.

Answer (score 0):

don't use return in while loop. instead, use a variable and use it for condition. also no need to make it true since all the time the condition is true until you pressed n or N

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int rollDice(void);
bool playGame(void);

int main(void)
{
    srand((unsigned)(time(NULL)));
    char userInput;
    bool again = true;
    while (again==true)
    {
        printf("Would you like to play again?");
        scanf("%c", &userInput);
        if (userInput == 'n' || userInput == 'N')
        {
            again = false;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the totals after the user quits you need to store them outside of the `playGame` function.

The return value from `playGame` is pointless at the moment, so let's use it to indicate whether the player won:

```
bool playGame(void)
{
    int point, total;
    printf("The game is starting!\n");
    total = rollDice();
    printf("You rolled: %d\n", total);
    if (total == 7 || total == 11)
    {
        printf("Wow it's your lucky day! You Win!\n");
        return true;
    }
    else if (total == 2 || total == 3 || total == 12)
    {
        printf("Unlucky! You Lose!\n");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        point = total;
        printf("Your Point is: %d\n", point);
        while (true)
        {
            total = rollDice();
            printf("You rolled: %d\n", total);
            if (total == point)
            {
                printf("You made your point! You Win!\n");
                return true;
            }
            else if (total == 7)
            {
                printf("Thats a %d. You Lose!\n", total);
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

And a slight rewrite of `main`:

```
int main(void)
{
    srand((unsigned)(time(NULL)));
    int total = 0;
    int wins = 0;
    char userInput;
    while (true)
    {
        total += 1;
        if (playGame())
        {
            wins += 1;
        }
        printf("Would you like to play again?");
        scanf("%c", &userInput);
        if (userInput == 'n' || userInput == 'N')
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("Of %d games, you won %d.", total, wins);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi @molbdnilo Just a quick question. In my text book we need to use  bool (void). When we return false at the end of the function - what are we actually doing? i don't see the difference in return false or true at the end of the function....